# UIImage loaded from file is partly black

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage

I am working on an app that has to save and load a variable number of UIImages. At the moment I am testing it with 126 Images.

I use a for loop to write every UIImage's data to a file, and another for loop to load the images again.
I use the following code to save the UIImages to files:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *component = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ImageFile%i.png",[sing.externComponentCounter intValue]];
sing.externComponentCounter = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[sing.externComponentCounter intValue]+1];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:component];
self.sideOneImagePath = component;
NSData *imageOneData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.sideOneImage);
[imageOneData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

externalCounter is a NSNumber property of my singleton object sing.

For loading the UIImages I use:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.sideOneImagePath];
self.sideOneImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

This code often works perfectly fine, however the UIImages sometimes have black bars or lines on the bottom.
For example https://www.dropbox.com/s/8qt2x45sqqnkwzy/image1.JPG?dl=0

Notice that the black bar on the bottom of the picture should not be there because it now makes it impossible to read the whole text on the picture.
Up to now I was not able to recognize a pattern for when this happens, it just seems to happen randomly. It never happens to a single picture but always to all of those 126 UIImages. Either it works perfectly fine or all of the pictures have a black bar which varies in size.

I am testing the app on a iPhone 6 with the latest iOS version and I am using the latest Xcode version.

Unfortunately I have absolutely no idea what causes my problem and I have not found any similar problem on the internet.

Thank you in advance, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: looks like you don't have the full image when you write it out... where does the original image come from?

Comment: I tend to think Dylan's assessment is right. It seems as if something in the image loading process is causing a problem. If you're loading the images concurrently, try changing to sequentially for troubleshooting purposes. I bet if you do that, if anything goes awry it will be just one image. Anyway, I used to see images like that back in dial-up modem days when connections were interrupted in the middle of transferring images.

Comment: This will happen if you have corrupted or partial data, you need to ensure the entire image has downloaded without error.

Comment: The image originally comes from the iPhone photo library by using an UIImagePickerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it's been more than two years I'm answering my own question for others.

The problem was that I wrote all the files to disk at the same time. Apparently this is too much.

I simply changed the application logic to make sure the images get saved as soon as they are added by the user rather then in the end.